# Code C: Enter an string, do not allow enter special characters such as @

Tags: c

```
char getText() {
    char text[100];
    int c = 0;
    do {
        __fpurge(stdin);
        printf("Enter text: ");
        gets(text);
        while (text[c] != '\0') {
            if ((text[c] != '@')) {
                if (text[c] == '@') {
                    printf("Contain @\n");
                }
            } else break;
            c++;
        }
    } while (1);
    return text;
}
```

I have this function check input string user enter. If string contain '@'. Require user enter again 
If string not contain '@'. Accept string and return string.
 But I can't break the loop. Anyone can help me solve problem. Thank first.

Comment: read your code out loud: "if text[c] != @ then is text[c] = @" - hang on, it can't possibly be != and = at the same time...

Comment: Just a side note: You need to reset `c` to 0 before entering the inner `while`-loop.

Comment: The title says: "special characters such as ...". I would take this as **any** special character with `@` only being an example.

Comment: That break is only breaking out of the inner loop. It's not breaking out of the while(1) loop. You probably want to put a conditional in the while(1) loop that checks if you've got a good string.

Answer (score 0):

Rather writing:

```
while (text[c] != '\0') {
    if ((text[c] != '@')) {
        if (text[c] == '@') {
            printf("Contain @\n");
        }
    } else break;
}
```

The followed condition tells the compiler to compare the `text[c]` and `@` when the `text[c]` isn't equal to `@`, which makes no sense at all.

Try this:

```
while (text[c] != '\0') {
    if (text[c] == '@') printf("Contain @\n");
    else break;
    // ...
}
```

Also, remember that using `gets()` is considered to be dangerous, [learn how & why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/11471113).

You may rather use the `fgets()`:

```
fgets(text, MAX, stdin); // #define MAX 100, playing with magical numbers
                         // isn't considered good
```